# IPTables Ignoring Rule To Redirect Web Traffic

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, redirection, administration

I am trying to do something very simple. I am trying to force all web request to go to my local webserver. I start by activating said webserver on my Kali Linux VirtualBox machine

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

Then I redirect all web traffic with iptables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
```

Check to make sure the changes took effect

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L
```

They did

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https to:127.0.0.1:80
```

Now when I go to google.com or even example.com I just go to google.com as I normally would. How can I make the changes actually take effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to google.com, your packet never visit PREROUTING chain.
Use OUTPUT instead.[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion. sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80 sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80 . But after doing sudo iptables -L it looks like the output command is not being added. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Wait, nevermind. It's working.

Comment: I'm receiving an error stating that this site can not provide a secure connection. I suppose I should not be surprised when considering HTTPS. Which begs the question, how do coffee shops redirect users to the terms of service page people need to agree to before they start using the internet?